# mysqlclient can't select rows which are inserted after MySQLdb.connect()

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, mysql-python

I have something weird in mysqlclient v1.3.10 (python 3).

Say I create a database connection `db = MySQLdb.connect(host='localhost', user='root', passwd='', db='test')`, then I insert a new row using Sequel Pro. If I select the new row using `cursor = db.cursor(); cursor.execute('''select ...''')`, it returns nothing.

I found doing `db.commit()` could fix the problem. Is it safe to do so, because I only want to perform `select` in this script? Will `commit()` do anything to the database, even without `insert` or `update` queries before it? What would be the appropriate way to accomplish this problem? Thanks.